# How to add popconfirm from antd design to file removal action

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Antd Design library in my react app. 
I have a form wihch contains [File Upload](https://ant.design/components/upload/)

I want to show [PopConfirm](https://ant.design/components/popconfirm/) each time the user is trying to remove uploaded file.
But the problem is: PopConfirm require React Element as children,and antd uploader seems doesn't provide acess to it.

But may be there is some another solution?

I've seen this question: 
[How to add PopConfirm for removeFile an image file in ant-d upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035890/how-to-add-popconfirm-for-removefile-an-image-file-in-ant-d-upload)

But there problem was solved by showing modal.
It's not quite what i want. Elsewhere in app always used PopConfirm, and for some reason where will be used modal. I really hope there is solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no build-in way to achieve this.

The cleanest way is to use `Modal`:

```js
function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setVisible(prev => !prev);
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal okText="Yes" cancelText="No" visible={visible} onCancel={toggle}>
        Are you sure delete this task?
      </Modal>
      <Upload {...props} onRemove={toggle}>
        <Button>
          <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
        </Button>
      </Upload>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The only solution is to implement your own `Upload` with `antd` components and use `Popconfirm` on the components of the uploaded file.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I will try to implement custom File Uploader using Antd's.